# How do i pass the values from html.editorfor() to my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the code generated by the Visual Studio when i added a view for my Edit function

I want to pass the values inside the `<input>` generated by the `@Html.EditorFor()` from the view to my controller.

How can i access those values? Can i do it without manually declaring textboxes via `<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Surname" name="Surname" type="text">` ?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save","my",FormMethod.Post)){
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value=Model.Name, @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
found the answer, i simply needed to pass this code as an argument in my function inside the controller that would create an object User with properties inside `Include`
`public string Submit ([Bind(Include = "Name")] User user){ 
}`

Comment: You do not need the `[Bind]` attribute (all properties are included by default)